# Reading data from a PHP subarray

Tags: php, arrays

Arrays always blow my mind and even the simplest tasks sometimes seem impossible!

I need to read the value of [total] from [exact_matches]. How do I do it?

```
$result = Array ( 
           [exact_matches] => Array ( 
                [total] => 0 
                [members] => Array ( ) 
           ),
           [full_search] => Array ( 
                [total] => 1 
                [members] => Array ( ) 
           ) 
        )
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Total from where? There are two totals.

Comment: Which total?? please mention

Comment: Use $result['exact_matches']['total']

Comment: @Sunil. Thanks. Can't see the wood for the trees sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For level one you would do,

```
$total = $result['exact_matches']['total']; which would return 0;
```

for the second total

```
$total = $result['exact_matches']['full_search']['total']
```

which would return 1;

Answer (score -1):

First Total:

```
echo $result['exact_matches']['total'];
```

Second Total:

```
echo $result['exact_matches']['total']['full_search']['total'];
```

I don't know which total do you want

Comment: Enough for comment no need of answer